# I want to make a login page with Laravel 6 that share login info between Laravel and Codeigniter program in the same server

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, laravel-6.2

I want to make a login page with Laravel 6 that share login info between Laravel and Codeigniter program in the same server.

I have a Laravel 6 program that I made its login page direct the user to three other separated systems two made by Laravel and the third one made by the Codeigniter the idea is that I register the user email and password manually in the three systems and the fourth one too, so we have 4 programs one to login the three other systems with the same email and password in the three systems.
the main program is https://almoderator.com/home/login
and the systems page is  https://almoderator.com/home/systems

```
email:omarhesham1983@gmail.com password: 123456789
```

the code I wrote is working with the two Laravel systems but not working with the Codeigniter system (facebook system) and this is my code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
   <h2 class="text-center">Select Platform</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="d-block text-center d-md-flex justify-content-between small-width">
      <div>
         <form method="POST" action="https://almoderator.com/fb/home/login" class="needs-validation"  novalidate="">
            <div class="form-group">
               <input hidden id="email" type="email" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" class="form-control" name="username" tabindex="1" required="" autofocus="">
               <!-- <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Please fill in your email
                  </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <input hidden id="password" type="password" value="{{ Auth::user()->password }}" class="form-control" name="password" tabindex="2" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <button type="submit" class="btn" tabindex="4">
               <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
               </button>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
      <div>
         <form class="" action="http://almoderator.com/insta/insta_login" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="qg9YHNZsZI2wDjhE2XxvHC6A4VM1BjdcCn5kzTRl">                    
            <div class="form-group">
               <input hidden id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" placeholder="Enter email" required="" autofocus="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <input hidden value="{{ Auth::user()->password }}" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-footer">
               <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></button>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
      <div>
         <form class="" method="post" action="https://almoderator.com/mail/includes/login/custom.php">
            <div class="form-group">
               <input hidden type="text" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">  
               <input hidden type="password" value="{{ Auth::user()->password }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"> 
               <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></button>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

what I can do to make it woke i am new to the two frameworks laravel 6 and Codeigniter so please consider that.
please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

It's sound like you want to implement [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/). To dedicate authentication logic to a separate server.

I hope you don't store password of user without encryption. But according this line you don't know it.

```
<input hidden value="{{ Auth::user()->password }}" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Usually `Auth::user()->password` password are encrypted so it will return not a valid password.

If you have several application and try to submit POST request from one to another you probably will face to [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf) each of your app has it's on way to generate and validate `csrf-token` so you need to disable it or make common way to generate and validate them.

Comment: By description it's sound really weird. I strongly recommend you to research about  OAuth2.

Comment: my problem is with the fires system only the Facebook system made by Codeigniter